# Python logrotate options

Tags: python, logging, python-2.4, logrotate

What is the correct process for having logrotate manage files written to by the python logging module? Usually I would use a WatchedFileHandler but I need to target 2.4, which does not have this class. Is there a function in the logging module which i can attach to a HUP handler, perhaps, to have it reopen the logfile?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you copy the source of `WatchedFileHandler` from a later version and adapt it, if needed, so that it works on 2.4.

Comment: For those of you who want to do thi, it is in Lib/logging/handlers.py. I ended up just using TimedRoatingFieHandler and having python do the rotation for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `logrotate` utility needs to be told which files to rotate, and with what options.  You might want to override the standard `WatchedFileHandler` class to make entries required in `/etc/logrotate.d` as part of your module load sequence before logging begins.